# Нужно преобразовать словарь в виде строки в обычный словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, dict, type-conversion

Код:

```py
foo_text_dict = "message='21', fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to=None, media=None, reply_markup=None, entities=[], views=None, forwards=None, replies=None"
print(dict(foo_text_dict))
```

Ошибка:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "some_path\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(dict(foo_text_dict))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Требуется получить на выходе обычный словарь python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно получить прямо таки словарь со всеми типами, а не просто строками, то можно воспользоваться `ast`. Т.к. исходная строка уж очень напоминает аргументы функции, напишем функцию-враппер, которая принимает эти аргументы и возвращает словарь из них.

```
import ast

def get_dict_from_str(dict_str):
    # это наша программа, которая определяет функции враппера
    program = f"""
def convert_to_dict():
    # враппер
    def params_to_dict(**kwargs):
        return kwargs
    # захардкодим переданную строку с аргументами в вызов враппера
    return params_to_dict({dict_str})
"""
    # компилируем всё это
    tree = ast.parse(program, mode='exec')
    code = compile(tree, filename='some', mode='exec')
    namespace = {}
    exec(code, namespace)
    # вызываем функцию из скомпилированного кода
    return namespace["convert_to_dict"]()
```

Можно обойтись и без `ast`. Хотя это считается менее безопасным.

```
def get_dict_from_str(dict_str):
    def params_to_dict(**kwargs):
        return kwargs
    namespace = {}
    exec(f"result = params_to_dict({dict_str})", locals(), namespace)
    return namespace["result"]
```

Ну ли даже без враппера, т.к. `dict()` тоже умеет собирать словарь из аргументов.

```
def get_dict_from_str(dict_str):
    namespace = {}
    exec(f"result = dict({dict_str})", locals(), namespace)
    return namespace["result"]
```

Во всех случаях исполнив это:

```
foo_text_dict = "message='21', fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to=None, media=None, reply_markup=None, entities=[], views=None, forwards=None, replies=None"
print(get_dict_from_str(foo_text_dict))
```

Получим:

```
{'message': '21', 'fwd_from': None, 'via_bot_id': None, 'reply_to': None, 'media': None, 'reply_markup': None, 'entities': [], 'views': None, 'forwards': None, 'replies': None}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял условие, то вот примерно как-то так:

```
foo_text_dict = "message='21', fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to=None, media=None, reply_markup=None, entities=[], views=None, forwards=None, replies=None"
list_text_dict=dict()
for et in foo_text_dict.split(", "):
    list_text_dict.update(dict([et.split("=")]))
print(list_text_dict)
```

Результат:

```
{'message': "'21'", 'fwd_from': 'None', 'via_bot_id': 'None', 'reply_to': 'None', 'media': 'None', 'reply_markup': 'None', 'entities': '[]', 'views': 'None', 'forwards': 'None', 'replies': 'None'}
```

Comment: Этот вариант тоже неплох но более правильным решением является ответ от @GrAnd